# How to use Cordova plugins for PhoneGap build

Tags: cordova, plugins, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build, hybrid-mobile-app

I am newbie in `PhoneGap` development, I have some problems with building my app using `PhoneGap` online service.
I have following structure now

[image]

As you can see I have `plugin` folder where a bunch of plugins

[image]

I used `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-camera` command to add plugins.
But when I upload source code to `PhoneGap` I follow such steps :

1. Add config file to the `www` folder
2. Compress `www` folder as zip archive
3. Upload to the PhoneGap

In other case it builds incorrectly.
But in this case it doesn't include my plugins added with cordova cli command.

What is correct way to add this plugins to make phonegap recognize them.
Maybe I am doing something completely incorrectly, please help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are using PhoneGap Build? Build? Also known as PGB.

PGB plugins do not work like this.

You don't need to add them or folders, you just add the line in the config file for each one.

Instructions are here:  http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/configuring_plugins.md.html

It's actually very easy for PGB.